# Is there a way to make Microsoft Windows 7 Taks Scheduler use a 24-hour clock?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

When I set ISO date and time formats in 'region and language', the Microsoft Task Scheduler uses ISO date and time formats for date and duration, but sticks to AM/PM format for time of day in the 'triggers' column. Can this be changed? Is there an alternative (ISO conforming) task scheduler UI for MSOS?

Answer (score 0):

12/24 hour clock settings for all applications should be set by Windows settings, in the same way the regional and keyboard settings are used system-wide.